# How to get each field of json doc in XQUERY Marklogic?

Tags: json, xquery, marklogic

How to get each field of json doc in XQUERY Marklogic?

```
let $doc :=
{
"field1" :'t',
"field2" : 'th',
"filed4": 'the'

}

return
$doc//??,
{
"New Filed" : "Added"
}
```

So how can we get the output like below ?

```
{ "field1" :'t', "field2" : 'th', "filed4": 'the' ,"New Filed" : "Added"}
```

Answer (score 1):

One approach: use the `xdmp:from-json()` to convert the immutable JSON node to a mutable map and then set the field:

```
return xdmp:from-json($doc) => map:with("NewField", "Added")
```

For more detail, see:  https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:from-json

Hoping that helps,

Answer (score 0):

A JSON object is really just a specialized map. So you can use map operators, like the `+` [union operator](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/app-dev/hashtable#id_71045):

```
let $doc := object-node
{
"field1" :'t',
"field2" : 'th',
"filed4": 'the'
}

return 
  $doc + map:entry("NewField", "added")
```